# How can I make this jQuery slider automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am going to be totally honest and tell you that I got this slider from a download somewhere, my knowledge of Javascript is very small.

I am trying to get the slider to automatically go to the next image or piece of content every 4 or 5 seconds, and I'd like to make it stop when the mouse hovers onto the piece of content.

here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    if(jQuery("#slider").length){
        var totalImages = jQuery("#slider > li").length, 
            imageWidth = jQuery("#slider > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery("#slider-wrap").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

        jQuery("#slider").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
            if(jQuery("#slider").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#slider").is(":animated")){
                jQuery("#slider").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function(){
            if(jQuery("#slider").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery("#slider").is(":animated")){
                jQuery("#slider").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your not far off, basically you just need to reuse your next click function in a timer, like so:

```
// Autoslide
timer = window.setInterval("autoSlide()", 1000);
function autoSlide(){ jQuery("#gallery-next").click(); }
```

so, every 1 second (1000ms) it will click the next button and slide. You will have to write something to reset the slider back to the start. and if you want to pause the slideshow on hover:

```
jQuery('#slider').hover(function(){
   window.clearInterval(timer);
}, function(){
   timer = window.setInterval("autoSlide()", 1000);
});
```

you might be able to store timer in a var and just call the var again, i'm just copying out some of my code, so if somebody wants to correct me please do!

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this inside the document.ready function:

```
var autoNext = setInterval(
    function() {
        jQuery("#gallery-next").click();
    },
    4000
);

jQuery("#id-of-the-content-that-stops-auto-scroll").mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(autoNext);
    jQuery(this).unbind('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: Hi, I like this method,  but when you unhover the autoscroll doesn't autoscroll again until you reload the page.

Comment: Hi.  I think that @ShanRobertson's answer is closer to what you are looking for.  Let me know if his answer doesn't work for you.